# Memory access time optimization in a lookup table

Tags: arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, lookup, lookup-tables

I would like to use a lookup table containing 2^32 (=4294967296) elements (`int8_t`).

I would like to know if I could possibly reduce access time in this lookup window by splitting it into a multidimensional lookup table.

For instance, in this context, one multi-dimensional corresponding lookup table would be:

```c
int8_t lookup_table[2^8][2^8][2^8][2^8].
```

Therefore, a `int32_t` index for the original lookup table would get split into four `int8_t` indices, which are used as an entry for the multidimensional array.

Could this reduce access time?

Comment: Making it multi-dimensional won't help. If you know anything about the access pattern then you may be able to reorganise the array to get better locality (and so benefit from caching). Given that you're mapping 32 bits to 8 bits though there must be an awful lot of redundancy, so there's probably a better way - maybe you could give a bit more context and people may then be able to suggest better solutions than a humungous lookup table?

Comment: Indeed there is a lot of redundancy. My purpose is exposed in one of my previous posts: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852911/binary-trees-getting-the-path-of-an-element-from-its-signature) -> The question is: is lookup table access more or less time-consuming than going through the binary tree iteratively.

Comment: One important thing to bear in mind is that with typical modern CPU architectures, a cache miss can cost you a few hundred instruction cycles. That's an awful lot of computation that you could have been doing instead. So, unless you know something about the access pattern, so that you can reduce the no of cache misses compared to pseudo-random access pattern, then you might want to consider some sort of computation approach, or perhaps some means of compressing the mapping data structure.